# How to automate password input with scp?

Tags: python, pexpect

I tried pexpect for this

Here's what i am trying to do.

copy >1gig file using scp to a network device. i am using below code for this.

`child = pexpect.spawn(f'scp /folder/images/{image_name} {device_name}:/location:')
child.expect("password:")
child.sendline(pwd)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)`

this code stuck on below line.

`2019-10-17 05:42:51,309 - file_sync.py - INFO - Copying the <imageName> to <Device_name>`

it doesn't show password prompt and seems like everything happens silently in the background and after few seconds i see TimeOut expection error on the console.

Is there any way to make it interactive (similar to subprocess) or any other method using which i can input the password interactively and see the file transfer progress on the console?

```
child = pexpect.spawn(f'scp /folder/images/{image_name} {device_name}:/location:')
child.expect("password:")
child.sendline(pwd)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Comment: you can directly use scp in your Konsole

Comment: when you say directly, do you mean manually? above code is part of python script i created. it does lot of checks on network device before start uploading the image on network device. and i want to automate this